# HighCharts pie chart labels not displayed properly

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have taken an example Highcharts plnkr and edited it to match my requirements.
Below is the plnkr that I have developed. https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview
Here all the labels and icons for the labels are displayed properly. But when I include it in my application, the icons for the labels are not displayed properly. 
It is displayed as below
[image]

My label code is as below

```
 labelFormatter: function () {
                    return '<div class="legend-label-md row" style=" border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-bottom: 5px"><span class="col-md-10">' + this.name +
                    '</span><span class="col-md-2" >' + this.value +
                    '%</span></div> ';
            }
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a different CSS? Please try to recreate the problem in a live demo or provide a link to a site that will be showing the issue.

Comment: I have just updated the plnkr. Is there any way that the right side value be right intended and also the line covering the legend icon.

Comment: After the update this seems to be a duplicate of this question, so let's continue there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474750/highchart-legend-customization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highchart legend customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474750/highchart-legend-customization)