# Highchart legend customization

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have a highchart- pie chart and I customized the labels as below. But I couldn't able to find how to move the value to right side(right intended). also the lines at the bottom of each legend to cover the legend icon also.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview

My legend code

```
 labelFormatter: function () {
                    return '<div class="legend-label-md row" style=" border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-bottom: 5px"><span class="col-md-10">' + this.name +
                    '</span><span class="col-md-1" >' + this.value +
                    '%</span></div> ';
                }
```

Comment: by "right intended" do you mean "right justified"?

Comment: Yes. Also can we hover on the legend item, can we show the value on the pie chart.

Comment: @indra257 Values in the legend are aligned to the right side. Maybe you could add an image of the chart you are trying to get? By "show the value on the pie chart" do you mean tooltip? Please explain this in the edited question and maybe add some images for better understanding.

Comment: @KacperMadej http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595600/angular2-highcharts-pie-chart-size-based-on-the-width-of-the-panel